# Scraping authenticated website in node.js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, meteor

I want to scrape my college website (moodle) with node.js but I haven't found a headless browser able to do it. I have done it in python in just 10 lines of code using RoboBrowser:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
url = "https://cas.upc.edu/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fatenea.upc.edu%2Fmoodle%2Flogin%2Findex.php%3FauthCAS%3DCAS"
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open(url)
form = browser.get_form()
form['username'] = 'myUserName'
form['password'] = 'myPassword'
browser.submit_form(form)
browser.open("http://atenea.upc.edu/moodle/")
print browser.parsed
```

The problem is that the website requires authentication. Can you help me? Thanks!

PD: I think this can be useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-scraper but I can't get it working.

Comment: http://casperjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to read a 3rd party website, and 'scrape' particular pieces of information, you could use a library such as [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to achieve this in Node.

Cheerio is a *"lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server"*. This means that given a String representation of a DOM (or part thereof), cheerio can traverse it in much the same way as jQuery can.

An [example from Max Ogden](http://maxogden.com/scraping-with-node.html) show how you can use the `request` module to grab HTML from a remote server and then pass it to `cheerio`:

```
var $ = require('cheerio')
var request = require('request')

function gotHTML(err, resp, html) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  var parsedHTML = $.load(html)
  // get all img tags and loop over them
  var imageURLs = []
  parsedHTML('a').map(function(i, link) {
    var href = $(link).attr('href')
    if (!href.match('.png')) return
    imageURLs.push(domain + href)
  })
}

var domain = 'http://substack.net/images/'
request(domain, gotHTML)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already know how to scrape a public website in js, the problem is that I want to scrape a page that needs authentication.

Comment: Then why don't you explain that in your question?

Comment: I don't explain it but it's clearly seen in the python code.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/selenium_installation/installing_selenium_libraries/) has support for multiple languages and multiple platforms and multiple browsers.